# broken dockerfile : github deploy key no longer copied correctly

Tags: git, ssh, docker

The following snippet worked fine a month ago (the last time i ran the container.)  It doesn't today.  Why?

```
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh && \
    mv /root/deployment_key /root/.ssh/id_rsa &&  cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com,$(getent hosts github.com | awk '{ print $1 }') > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

When i `cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, the public key is only about half as long as it's supposed to be.  The private key is correct in `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`.

The next line (a `git clone` of a private repo) fails with

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
The command '/bin/sh -c git clone ssh://FOO@github.com/FOO/PRIVAT_REPO.git' returned a non-zero code: 128
```

I'm running docker Version 1.12.1-rc1-beta23 (build: 11375)  on OSX, but it fails on windows 10, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv /root/deployment_key /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This means your `Dockerfile` includes an [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add) or [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy) command which populated `/root/deployment_key` first, *before* the `RUN mv` command.

Try to make another image from your existing Dockerfile by:

- amending the `Dockerfile` for that new image in order to `RUN echo /root/deployment_key/id_rsa.pub` and see if it is there, with the expected content and content length,
- split your RUN command in order to isolate the `RUN mv` part and check its content, before proceeding with the rest of that RUN command.

Comment: @gvoysey private? I am talking in my answer about id_rsa.pub: the *public* key.

Comment: ah.  no, as i stated above, the public key is not being copied correctly.

Comment: @gvoysey Exactly: that is what I mention in the answer: check if the public key is copied correctly in `/root/deployment_key` (before the mv). If not, you need to resolve that first.

Comment: once more: that's the private key. and yes, it's being copied correctly.  The problem is with `ssh-keyscan github.com,$(getent hosts github.com | awk '{ print $1 }') > ~/.ssh/known_hosts`, because known_hosts is  truncated halfway through.